# mail() function bouncing: 550-do not have sufficient privileges

Tags: php, email

I'm sending emails from a PHP contact form. My send code is as follows:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: website.com <noreply@website.com>
Reply-To: $form[email]";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Although the message is being delivered, I'm also getting the following message:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; xxxx.com
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost
Arrival-Date: Thu, 11 Dec 2014 15:17:25 -0500

Final-Recipient: RFC822; acct@myserver.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Remote-MTA: DNS; myserver.com
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550-You do not have sufficient privileges to send mail to this address.  Please authenticate and try again. (in reply to RCPT TO command)
Last-Attempt-Date: Thu, 11 Dec 2014 15:17:26 -0500
```

My hosting company tells me it's a problem with the code. My research shows that it's because the From name isn't set in the headers, but it is in my code.

I'm using cPanel/WHM to manage the server. I have multiple accounts setup and this is the only one where this is happening despite the code being virtually identical. The only difference is that this particular client is managing his emails through a different service, so his MX records point elsewhere.

Is this a server issue or a code issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: Stop using `mail()` altogether.  Use something like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer.  Then, you can authenticate to your STMP servers, set headers correctly, and anything else you might need to get this working with your host.

Comment: i think you need to add `"\r\n"` between and quotes around email `$form['email']`. Also i dont think you need the mime ver etc.

Comment: @csaw - I don't need the "\r\n" as the linebreak is included, and that's coming through alright. I don't have any quotes around the `$form[email]`, so not sure what you mean there.